# powershell conditional IsNullorEmpty not working as planned

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a conditional statement in Powershell that tests for the existence of data in a registry value name.  I have declared the following path as a variable.  `HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings`

I have also used the **Get-ItemProperty cmdlet** to declare a variable for the registry name itself (i.e. **ProxyOverride**).  When I write my conditional statement I am using:

`[string]::IsNullorEmpty($proxyoverridevariable)`

When the conditional statement runs it always reports back that the Registry Value ProxyOverride is not Null or Empty even though I know it is.

What I know so far is that, if I delete **ProxyOverride** from the registry, the conditional statement works.  I want it to work if the data field is blank.

```
$regKey="HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"

$proxyoverride = "localhost;127.0.0.1"

$proxyexception = Get-ItemProperty -path $regKey -name ProxyOverride -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

if ([string]::IsNullorEmpty($proxyexception)) { Set-ItemProperty -Path $regKey -name ProxyOverride -value $proxyoverride }

else { write-host "Value not empty" }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there anything in it when you doable click the value in regedit? Do you get back a number with: (Get-ItemProperty -Path $regKey -Name ProxyOverride -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).ProxyOverride.Length

Comment: right now the value of ProxyOverride is blank from my perspective.  But when I add the ProxyOverride.Length I get a 0 (zero).

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because the value is present. If it's empty PowerShell returns it along with some other provider related properties (e.g PSPath, etc) and so on, that's why IsNullorEmpty reports always False. When the value is not present all other properties are not returned and you get the expected result.

Here's a workaround, query the value itself and then check if its empty or null:

```
$proxyexception = (Get-ItemProperty -path $regKey -name ProxyOverride -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).ProxyOverride
```